# What is the proper way of editing/updating many-to-many items in DB?

Tags: database, update

I have **film's storage** (3 tables in database):

- `films`{`id`:int, `film`:string}
- `genres`{`id`:int, `genre`:string},
- `films_genres`{`film_id`:int, `genre_id`:int, `probability`:int(%)}
  (`film_id`, `genre_id`) is UNIQUE KEY(compound key).

For example:

```
films = 
{
    1 : 'Some film 1',
    2 : 'Some film 2'
}

genres = 
{
    1 : 'comedy',
    2 : 'action',
    3 : 'cartoon'
}

films_genres = 
{
    (1, 1, 100),
    (1, 2, 50),
    (1, 3, 70),
    (2, 1, 50),
    (2, 3, 100)
}
```

Also I have **web form** for editing/updating film genres and their probabilities where I can **`insert`** new genres, **`delete`** and **`update`** existing genres.

**Suggest me better of 2 ways to EDIT/UPDATE table `films_genres` via web edit form and SQL?:**

1) If I want to EDIT film genres with probability in web edit form I can UPDATE both of fields `genre (genre_id)` and `probability` via SQL query for table `films_genres`, but I think this is a **bad way**. Also I can INSERT, DELETE film genres with probabilities via SQL.

2) If I want to EDIT film genres with probability in web edit form I can UPDATE only `probability` and not `genre (genre_id)` via SQL query  for table `films_genres`. Also I can INSERT, DELETE film genres with probabilities via SQL. And I think this is **good way**.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Would you please edit your question to make it more clear?

Comment: Excuse me if I asked not clearly. I've got already the answer on my question below.

Comment: by improving the legibility of your question, other users apart from yourself can benefit from it.

Comment: Ok! I've tried to write more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a third alternative.

You should consider that the films_genres table has a primary key that is a [compound (key)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) consisting of both the film_id together with the genre_id, and then deal with updates to the films_genres table from that perspective.

In other words, you should consider that the films-genres table, in some sense, has only two top-level attributes: (a) the primary key and (b) the probabilities -- where this primary key is a compound key consisting of two columns: film_id and genre_id.

Thus, you can update the probability entry in the film-genres table for a given row having compound key of film-id / genre-id (without necessarily deleting a different entry).  It is perfectly fine to have multiple films-genres rows for any given film (or any given genre).

---

This third alternative contrasts with your first and second alternatives:

> 1) I can update both of fields in films_genres: genre (genre_id) and probability.

You should address/locate/identify rows in the films_genres table using the full primary key, which is a compound key, not just the films_id column alone.  Rows with the same film_id but different genre_id are separate rows that should not necessarily be updated together due to an other update in that table involving the same films_id.

> 2) I can update only probability of current film genre and not genre (genre_id) in films_genres. However if I want to update some film genre (genre_id) I need delete the old one: (film_id, genre_id_old, probability_old) and then insert a new one: (film_id, genre_id_new, probability_new).

You should address rows in the films_genres table using the compound key, not just the films_id column alone.  Rows with the same film_id but different genre_id are separate rows that should not necessarily be updated together.  A film can have multiple films_genre rows by having different genre_id's, so no need to delete one in order to add another.

If a given films_genres primary key already exists, then you "update", otherwise you insert.  (Remember, here by primary key, I mean the compound key consisting of film_id + genre_id.)  There is no need to delete unless you want to remove the probability for the compound key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eric for your detailed explanation! Your third alternative is just my second decision/way and sorry if I asked not clearly.